# bigquery - partition on custom fields -- only for standardSQL?

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning, legacy-sql

I just saw that I can create a `custom partitioned` table in BigQuery. Meaning partitioned by any `timestamp` column.

**However**, the newly created table can only be accessed and queried from `StandardSQL`!

Is there a way to query the new tables from Legacy?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just at the begining of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions) says in limitations you don't have Legacy SQL support.

**Partitioned tables are subject to the following limitations:**

- The partitioning column must be either a scalar DATE or TIMESTAMP
  column. While the mode of the column may be REQUIRED or NULLABLE, it
  cannot be REPEATED (array-based). Additionally, the partitioning
  column must be a top-level field. You cannot use a leaf field from a
  RECORD (STRUCT) as the partitioning column.
- You cannot use legacy SQL
  to query partitioned tables or to write query results to partitioned
  tables.
- You cannot use wildcard tables when querying partitioned
  tables.
- You cannot use DML statements to modify partitioned tables.

Comment: Is Legacy support on the road map in any way? And you could add the information about the missing support for Legacy into the UI, for example at the `?` at Partition field.

Comment: There is no mention that it is considered, so it's just speculation if will or not.

Comment: There's no plan to support it for legacy SQL. We think it'll be better to invest on more new features than supporting legacy SQL, which will be deprecated. It'll be common for new features to support standard SQL only.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to state LegacySql to `false`, for example:

```
var projectId = 'xxxxxxx';
    
var request = {
  query: 'select * from project.database.table',
  useLegacySql: false
};
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
```